# NSIS - Compile with opcode re arranged to prevent access to source code

Tags: nsis

I am trying to reduce and make as difficult as possible the ability to access my source code after being compiled by NSIS. I have read that the only way to reduce the chance of unzipping is to modify the order of the opcodes in the Source\fileform.h from the source code and then Compile the new version.

This is a bit over my head. I was wondering if anyone has done this before and willing to post one they have done. (Or create one for me?)

Main reason for this is I have info that I encrypt using blow-fish within NSIS and do not want the chance oFf someone finding out what the encryption keys are. (Used for licencing the software) I understand noting is fool proof, but just want it as difficult as possible.

I know its asking a lot, but could really this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there are any publicly available modified builds like that. And if there were and it got popular, the decompilers would just add support for it.

I have a complete step-by-step guide to building NSIS [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=3041957&postcount=32).

If you know C/C++, Delphi or C# you could build your own private NSIS plug-in that handles the encryption details.

No matter what you do, somebody who knows how to use a debugger can easily set a breakpoint on the blow-fish plug-in and view your key. The only way around that is a custom plug-in or an external application that handles the cryptography internally...